# Bash equivalent of tcsh M-$?

Tags: bash, tcsh

Way back while studying I used tcsh as my main shell and it had this nifty feature of being able to correct a misspelled command name by pressing Escape-$ which would the. change eg “bsah” to “bash”

Now I needed it (apparently kustomize is not keyboard friendly) but could not recall ever having seen this in bash.

Can bash do this and if so how?

Comment: The only other shell (that I'm aware of) that offers correction of mistyped command names is `zsh`, with its `CORRECT` shell option set.

Comment: With `shopt -s dirspell cdspell`, you can get `bash` to correct directory names on pathname completions and `cd` commands respectively, but specifically spell-checking *command names* does not seem to be available in it.

Comment: FWIW, M-$ also works in zsh (in emacs mode, `spell-word` widget). Any particular reason to choose bash? Seems an odd choice to me especially when coming from tcsh. See also the `dvorak` option in case you're using a dvorak keyboards so the spelling corrections are tuned to that keyboard layout, and the `correct` and `correctall` opionts for the auto-correct (like tcsh's `correct` variable)

Comment: @Kusalananda I don't particular care about which sh-dialect I use as long as it can edit current line properly, and has a history to pick from (and preferably is supported by `kubectl completion ..`).  As my personal Mac has long since switched to zsh I might give it a try here too.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I typically only use a system a short while before installing a new, and bash is the default on Ubuntu which I like. Now I have a long lived system and can tune it more.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge in `bash`, there is no direct equivalent to the `M-$` feature in `tcsh` for correcting misspelled command names.

Bash offers some useful features like:

- tab completion
- command history
- command editing

These can help you to correct misspelled command names or navigate through previous commands effectively in Bash.

It doesn't offer the exact functionality of `M-$` in `tcsh`, but these features should be helpful.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html

Comment: Thanks.  I have used bash for many years so I knew most of these things.  Problem is that the manual is so large that unless you know exactly what it is called what you are looking for, it can be rather hard to find.

Answer (score -5):

Hit Arrow Up and edit the command however you like.

Comment: Did you actually read the question?